# How to asynchronously require modules in React application using webpack?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, webpack

In a React application, I would like to import a library called *flowtime.js* only for a certain route/path and then execute some more code. This library has a dependency called *Brav1toolbox*. Neither is available on npm.

My strategy is to use webpack’s `require` in the Component’s `componentDidMount` method. Here is my attempt :

```
componentDidMount() {
  require.ensure([ 'local/relative/path/to/lib/brav1toolbox.js'], function(require) {
    var f = require('local/relative/path/to/other/lib/Flowtime.js/js/flowtime.js');
  });
}
```

which results in the following error.

> Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: Brav1Toolbox is not defined

So Flowtime is being loaded but is not able to find Brav1Toolbox.

I am not experienced with either React or webpack so perhaps I have a misconception. I am trying to use webpack to only load those libraries if my users visit a path where those libraries are needed. [This is the webpack guide](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/tree/master/examples/code-splitting) I used as reference.

Thank you for trying to help.

Comment: did you have installed `flowtime.js`, or have you this lib in your local? webpack can't load the remote js files.

Comment: I edited my question to show that the libs are local. In fact, Flowtime.js is being run and is the one complaining about the absence of Brav1toolbox.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your version of webpack, but you are on the right track with code splitting / route chunking.

For webpack v2, I would recommend checking out the [Webpack documentation](https://webpack.js.org/guides/code-splitting-async/).

With webpack 2 you can require the libraries within the react containers / components where they are needed, and then dynamically load the code based on the path. An example of how you might be able to do this with react-router via two example routes, e.g. "/home" and "/about", is below:

```
<Route path="/home" getComponent={(nextState, callback) => {
    require.ensure([], require => {
        callback(null, require("./containers/home"));
    }, "Home");
}} />
<Route path="/about" getComponent={(nextState, callback) => {
    require.ensure([], require => {
        callback(null, require("./containers/about"));
    }, "About");
}} />
```

Comment: Webpack 2 adds support for `import()` which returns a Promise that resolves to the module. So you can do: `import('jquery').then($ => { ... })` for example